# How to add metrics to external services using aioprometheus and FastAPI?

Tags: python, prometheus, fastapi, starlette

I'm trying to add metrics to external services with `aioprometheus` in an app built with `FastAPI`. Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Say I have a wrapper App class as such:

```py
from aioprometheus import Registry, Counter, Histogram
from fastapi import FastAPI

class App:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.registry = Registry()
        self.counter = Counter(
            name="counts", doc="request counts"
        )
        self.latency = Histogram(
            name="latency",
            doc="request latency",
            buckets=[0.1, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2]
        )

        self.app = FastAPI()
        self._metrics()

    def _metrics(self):
        # Counter metrics
        @self.app.middleware("http")
        async def counter_metrics(request, call_next):
            response = await call_next(request)
            self.counter.inc(
                {"path": str(request.url.path), "status": response.status_code}
            )
            return response

        # Latency metrics
        @self.app.middleware("http")
        async def latency_metrics(request, call_next):
            start = time.time()
            response = await call_next(request)
            total_duration = time.time() - start
            self.latency.observe(
                {"path": str(request.url.path)}, total_duration
            )
            return response
        
        @self.app.on_event("startup")
        async def startup():
            self.app.include_router(some_router(...))

        self.registry.register(self.counter)
        self.registry.register(self.latency)
```

Basically, I have `Registry`, `Counter`, and `Histogram` initiated. In `_metrics`, I have `Counter` and `Histogram` specific logics that are later added to `Registry`. This will do its magic and catch the metrics when an endpoint in `some_router` is called (this is good! I would want to keep this, as well as having the external service metrics).

However, say I call an external service from `some_router` as such:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter

def some_router():
    router = APIRouter()

    @router.get("/some_router")
    async def some_router():
        response = await external_service()

        return response

    return router
```

In this case, how would I add metrics specifically to `external_service`, i.e., Latency of this specific external service?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://aioprometheus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/index.html#web-frameworks), you would need to attach your metrics to the [app instance](https://www.starlette.io/applications/#accessing-the-app-instance) using the generic `app.state` attribute (see the implementation of Starlette's [`State`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/212fa46b23be0701a5963cdeff14f05ed352e22a/starlette/datastructures.py#L674) class as well), so they can easily be accessed in the route handler—as metrics are often created in a different module than where they are used (as in your case). Thus, you could use the following in your `App` class, after instantiating the metrics:

```py
self.app.state.registry = registry
self.app.state.counter = counter
self.app.state.latency = latency
```

In your routers module, you could get the `app` instance using the `Request` object, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71298949/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804), and then use it to get the metrics instances (as shown below), which will let you add metrics to your `external_service`:

```py
from fastapi import Request
...
@router.get("/some_router")
async def some_router(request: Request):
    registry = request.app.state.registry
    counter = request.app.state.counter
    latency = request.app.state.latency

    response = await external_service()
    
    return response
```