# How to share variables between HTTP requests in FastAPI?

Tags: python, httprequest, fastapi, starlette

How can I share the value of variables between `HTTP` requests in FastAPI? For instance, I have a `POST` request in which I get some audio files and then I convert their info into a Pandas `Dataframe`. I would like to send that `Dataframe` in a `GET` request, but I can't access the `Dataframe` on the `GET` request scope.

```py
@app.post(
    path="/upload-audios/",
    status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK
)
async def upload_audios(audios: list[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    filenames = [audio.filename for audio in audios]
    audio_data = [audio.file for audio in audios]
    new_data = []
    final_data = []
    header = ["name", "file"]
    for i in range(len(audios)):
        new_data = [filenames[i], audio_data[i]]
        final_data.append(new_data)
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(final_data, columns=header)
    return f"You have uploaded {len(audios)} audios which names are: {filenames}"

@app.get("/get-dataframe/")
async def get_dataframe():
    pass
```

Comment: Store the requested data in a storage solution - like redis, sqlite, on disk, rdbms - wherever, then read it and create the dataframes when the user requests them. You'll also need to return them in a format that FastAPI can serialize properly.

Comment: @MatsLindh, so I need a database. But if I dont want to use a memory mechanism, the same thing could be done with  python context variables?

Comment: You could store it in-memory in your process - as long as you never expect to serve more than one user, and don't plan on having multiple workers active at the same time (which would have their own memory, so the worker handling the get would not necessarily be the same as the one handling the post). Do keep the data in-process, declare a dictionary outside of the functions, then assign to a key inside the dictionary inside the function - `foo = {}` at the top, then `foo['pd'] = ..` inside your functions.

Answer (score 12):

If you need read-only access to that variable, and/or you never expect it to be modified by some other request before reading it (in other words, you **never** expect to serve more than one client), as well as your app **does not** use [several workers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/)—since [each worker has its own things, variables and memory](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/concepts/#memory-per-process))—you could either (as mentioned by @MatsLindh in the comments above) declare a dictionary, e.g., `foo = {}`, outside the endpoints (in other words, globally) and assign a key to it inside the endpoint, e.g., `foo['pd'] = df`, (which you can later retrieve when another request arrives), or declare your variable as `global` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71383736/17865804)), or, preferably, [store the variable on the app instance](https://www.starlette.io/applications/#accessing-the-app-instance), which allows you to store arbitrary extra state using the generic `app.state` attribute—see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) on how to do this *before* the application starts up. For example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/create")
async def create_dataframe():
    # df = ...  # create the df here
    app.state.df = df
```

Then, inside the `get_dataframe` endpoint, you can retrieve the `df` like this:

```py
@app.get("/get")
async def get_dataframe():
    df = app.state.df
```

or, if the `app` instance is not available in the file from which you are working (let's say you have your endpoints defined in submodules, separately from the main module, as described [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#an-example-file-structure)), you could get the `app` instance from the `Request` object:

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.get('/get')
async def get_dataframe(request: Request):
    df = request.app.state.df
```

Otherwise, if you needed that variable/object to be **shared** among different clients, as well as among multiple processes/workers, that may also require read/write access to it, you should rather use a database storage, such as `PostgreSQL`, `SQLite`, `MongoDB`, etc., or `Key-Value` stores (Caches), such as [`Redis`](https://redis.io/), [`Memcached`](https://memcached.org/), etc. You may want to have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65699375/17865804) as well.