# 500 Undocumented Error: Internal Server Error when returning response in FastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am using FastAPI to make predictions using a ML model. When I give a `task_id` and `input`, the app should add it to the background task and return the response accordingly. However, I am getting `Error 500` when I try to do it.

After adding `task_id_globally`, it started throwing errors before it worked fine.

**Error**

```py
  File ".\app\main.py", line 36, in post
    return {'result': response_name[task_id_global]}
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

**Code**

```py
task_id_global = None
@app.get('/predict')
async def predict(task_id:int, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,solute,solvent):
    task_id_global = task_id
    if task_id == 0:
        background_tasks.add_task(predictions,solute,solvent)
        return {'success'}
    elif task_id == 1:
        background_tasks.add_task(predictions_two,solute)
        return {'success'}
    else:
        return "Give proper task_id"
    
response_name = [response, attach_drug_name()]

@app.get('/predict_solubility')
async def post():
    return {'result': response_name[task_id_global]}
```

Comment: What is the actual error that results in the 500 response from FastAPI? The console will have the actual error? Returning a set (the `{'success'}` value) from your API probably doesn't make sense either (since it can't be represented in JSON).

Comment: @MatsLindh I have added the error. It seems like the task_id value I have given is not assigned to `task_id_global`. How to rectify this

Comment: You can't assign a value to a variable outside your function; and in general, using global values in your application leads to further problems rather quickly. To make assignment to a variable outside of a function work, you can use a dict (since you can refer to the dict and update it), but generally you might want to move this to a more suitable queue than trying to keep it inside FastAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `task_id_global` to `None`, and thus, when calling `/predict_solubility` endpoint, it is trying to retrieve an element from the list using `response_name[None]`; hence, the error. So you should set `task_id_global` to `0`, which should point to some default value in your `response_name` list - even if `/predict` endpoint has not yet been called - or perform a check inside the second endpoint to see whether `task_id_global` is not `None` and then decide whether to proceed retrieving an item from the list. Next, inside `/predict` endpoint declare `task_id_global` as global before using it (using the `global` keyword), as, in the way it is currently declared, it is interpreted as a local variable, and hence,  the global one never gets affected by any changes occur to `task_id_global` inside the endpoint (have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)).

```
task_id_global = None

@app.get('/predict')
async def predict(task_id:int,solute,solvent):
    global task_id_global
    task_id_global = task_id
    ...
```

Also, depending on your task (e.g., if you have multiple requests concurrently accessing that global variable), you might want to consider other options, such as Redis for instance. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804).