# Accessing static variables in FastAPI with multiple workers

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a FastAPI application, where in I need to run a thread in parallel which will check for messages and consumes it. The challenge I have is, when I shutdown the server, the static variable MessageBroker.run_message_broker is not set to False, and application does not exit normally. I just started with FastAPI recently, what am I missing?

fastapi_n_thread.py

```
import time
import datetime
from fastapi import FastAPI
import asyncio
import uvicorn
import threading


app = FastAPI()


class MessageBroker:
    run_message_broker = True

    @staticmethod
    def init():
        # Intializing MQ, removed for simplicity
        print("Initializing Message Broker")

    @staticmethod
    def __get_message():
        # Code removed for simplicity
        return [{"msg_id": 1, "message": "hello"}]

    @staticmethod
    async def process_message():
        print("Starting message processing")
        while MessageBroker.run_message_broker:
            # print(f'Run loop? {MessageBroker.run_sqs_client} {datetime.datetime.now()}')
            try:
                message = MessageBroker.__get_message()
                if message:
                    # print(f"Got the message {message}")
                    continue
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Exception occurred {e}")
        print("Stopping message processing")


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    print("startup event")


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    before = MessageBroker.run_message_broker
    MessageBroker.run_message_broker = False
    after = MessageBroker.run_message_broker
    print(f"Shutdown event {before} - {after}")


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    """API root"""
    print({"message": f"AML Screening API is running asyncio {time.time()}"})
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    return {"message": f"AML Screening API is running asyncio {time.time()} start:{start} end:{end}"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sqs_thread = threading.Thread(target=MessageBroker.init)
    sqs_thread.start()
    uvicorn.run('fastapi_n_thread:app', host="0.0.0.0", port=8003,
                workers=5, limit_concurrency=4, limit_max_requests=20)
```

In the shutdown_event() method, when I set MessageBroker.run_message_broker to False, I thought the thread would stop. However, since I am using uvicorn (workers=5), looks like they are treated totally separate instances. How do I update global variables that are accessible across?

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Chris. When I use async def, even the global keyword is not helping. It is still functioning the same way. Global variable works across HTTP requests, but it is not accessible within the Thread.