# Isolating parrallel runs in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, fastapi

I want to run a particular script in parallel. However, variables are
shared across threads, causing an issue. As an example, consider the
scenario below: DB_Mode is initially set to 1 by default but is
overwritten to 0.  Is there a way to isolate these parallel runs to
prevent the sharing of variables (there are way too many of those in
actual script then just DB Mode so can't do threading.lock), either globally or locally? I lack control over the
actual script so can't modify anything on that front. In this case,
what is the method to execute the script in parallel while avoiding
shared variable access?

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from typing import List, Optional
import DB

def FindRequest(flag=False):
    print(flag, DB.DB_MODE)
    if (flag == True):
        DB.DB_MODE = 0
    print(flag, DB.DB_MODE)
    return {}

def get_flag(flag):
    FindRequest(flag)
    return {}

async def process_request(flag, loop, executor):
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, get_flag, flag)
    return result

async def main():
    version_required = [True, False, True, False]
    tasks = []
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
    tasks = [process_request(request, loop, executor) for i, request in enumerate(version_required)]
    processed_data = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    executor.shutdown()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **subprocesses**, not **thread**. Threads are a bit misleading in Python for new-comers in Python. They are specifically designed to allow for asynchronous execution *but* without allowing parallel execution of multiple functions at once (you can lookup at [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)). The main advantage is allowing to share resources/variables without relying on inter-process communication. Besides, it is extremely fast to create a new thread compare to a subprocess. However, it is hard to manage properly and it is not going to help for tasks that are CPU bound instead of I/O bound. On the contrary, subprocess are kind of completely independent processes all different piece of code and eventually communicating with each other on occasion if requested.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html) are the official resources about how to use subprocesses with `asyncio`. You could also go for bare-bound [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) standard library, or [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor).