# FastAPI - How to get app instance inside a router?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I want to get the `app` instance in my router file, what should I do ?

My `main.py` is as follows:

```
# ...
app = FastAPI()
app.machine_learning_model = joblib.load(some_path)
app.include_router(some_router)
# ...
```

Now I want to use `app.machine_learning_model` in some_router's file , what should I do ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since [FastAPI is actually Starlette underneath](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/#details-about-the-request-object), you could store the model on the app instance using the generic `app.state` attribute, as described in Starlette's [documentation](https://www.starlette.io/applications/#storing-state-on-the-app-instance) (see [`State`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/212fa46b23be0701a5963cdeff14f05ed352e22a/starlette/datastructures.py#L674) class implementation too). Example:

```py
app.state.ml_model = joblib.load(some_path)
```

As for accessing the `app` instance (and subsequently, the model) from outside the main file, you can use the [`Request`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/#use-the-request-object-directly) object. As per Starlette's [documentation](https://www.starlette.io/applications/#accessing-the-app-instance), where a `request` is available (i.e., endpoints and middleware), the `app` is available on `request.app`. Example:

```py
from fastapi import Request

@router.get('/')
def some_router_function(request: Request):
    model = request.app.state.ml_model
```

Comment: May I add other request params in ```some_router_function``` ?

Comment: Yes. You can define params as usual.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm quite shocked that FastAPI does not provide any streamlined possibility to store Singletons for the service lifecycle.

Comment: Does this load model into memory only once and then pass the reference? I assume there is, since there is only one instance of the app running in the process?

Comment: @ruslaniv It does, and it would be best to initialise that variable inside a startup/lifespan event hanlder, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804). If you plan on having multiple workers active at the same time, you might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71613757/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804) as well.

Comment: Is it possible to define router-specific state? Suppose I have multiple routers, one per model; can I avoid loading them all in the top-level app's startup hook?