# Running FastAPI with HuggingFace Transformer Crashing API / Spawning Subprocess

Tags: subprocess, fastapi, huggingface-transformers, uvicorn

I love FastAPI. However, I'm not well-versed in the nuances of the "guts" behind its magic (uvicorn, watchgod, etc.)

I'm developing an API that will let users interact with a HiggingFace transformer model. Specifically, I'm using a [RobertaForQuestionAnswering](https://huggingface.co/consciousAI/question-answering-roberta-base-s-v2) model.

However, I'm running into a few problems that I'm unable to debug with the VSCode debugger. Trying to "step into" the problem doesn't yield anything at all.

Problems:

1. Even when I declare the `RobertaForQuestionAnswering` model at the top of my routes file like so:

```
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(data_dir)
model = RobertaForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(data_dir)
transformer_pipeline = pipeline(task="question-answering", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)

@router.post("/test")
async def test():
    return response_model(question="What is my name?", context="My name is Joe")
```

FastApi starts a new subprocess EVERY TIME the model is mentioned, and re-creates it EVERY TIME, which is very time consuming. I have tried to use FastAPI's dependency injection and a few other methods, but I think these efforts are futile since FastAPI creates a new ephemeral subprocess for every invocation of the transformer model.

2. When running the FastAPI app with uvicorn, and using a single worker (the default), the API "shuts down" gracefully whenever the transformer model is run. So, I need to run the app with `workers=2` like so:

```
uvicorn.run("project_name.api.webapp:init_fastapi_application",host=host,port=port, log_level='debug', workers=2)
```

Where `init_fastapi_application` is just a custom function that returns the app object. Running with multiple workers is a total "hacky" fix to the "graceful shut down" problem I'm having, and I frustratingly can't figure out why it fixes the problem!

TLDR;

1. How/why/when does FastApi create new subprocesses, and why are they being created every time I invoke a Hugging Face Transformer Model?
2. Why does running FastApi without multiple workers fail when trying to interact with the transformer model?

Tried:

1. Dependency injection with FastApi "Depends"
2. "Await"-ing the long transformer model creation
3. Using FastAPI "@asynccontextmanager"
4. Using "@app.on_event("startup")" to load the transformer model before app startup
5. Creating a singleton TransformerObject class to force FastApi to share the same object instance (which is futile because FastAPI creates a new subprocess every time)

EDIT:
I was able to access my state like so:

webapp.py:

```
def init_fastapi_application():

    @asynccontextmanager
    async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
        ''' Run at startup
            Initialise the Client and add it to request.state
        '''
        transformer_pipeline = TransformerQA.get_instance().model
        yield {'transformer_pipeline': transformer_pipeline}
        ''' Run on shutdown
            Close the connection
            Clear variables and release the resources
        '''
        print("in asynccontextmanager shutdown block")


    app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
    app.include_router(api_routers.routes.router)
    return app
```

routes.py:

```
@router.post("/test2")
async def test2(request: Request):
    model = request.state._state['transformer_pipeline']
    return model("What is my name?","My name is Joe")
```

But whenever the model is run (with a single worker),

```
print("in asynccontextmanager shutdown block")
```

Gets run, indicating the app gets shut down. Here is the full console output:

```
######### Start the app
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
######### Can hit endpoints that don't involve my 
######### model, and they work just fine here.
...
######### Hit the /test2 endpoint (returns the payload to the client still which is interesting)
INFO:     Shutting down
INFO:     Waiting for connections to close. (CTRL+C to force quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:39138 - "POST /test2 HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
in asynccontextmanager shutdown block
INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
INFO:     Finished server process [126197]
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71613757/17865804)?

Comment: Wrap it around JS instead https://huggingface.co/docs/huggingface.js/index?

Comment: Links from Chris are helpful!

Comment: Hi @Chris, I updated the question. I'm still getting the mysterious shutting down problem when running with a single worker.

Comment: Also, I can't thank you enough for your comment @Chris . Even if I can't figure out why it shuts down when only using one worker, you've solved my problem of re-creating the model every time a route is hit.