# FastAPI - How can I modify request from inside dependency?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

How can I modify request from inside a dependency? Basically I would like to add some information (`test_value`) to the request and later be able to get it from the view function (in my case `root()` function).

Below is a simple example:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Request

app = FastAPI()

def test(request: Request):
    request['test_value'] = 'test value'

@app.get("/", dependencies=[Depends(test)])
async def root(request: Request):
    print(request.test_value)
    return {"test": "test root path."}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Option 1

You could store arbitrary extra state to [`request.state`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#about-requeststate), and use the `Request` object inside the endpoint to retrieve the state (the relevant implementation of Starlette's `State` method and class can be found [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/8965f8849977b5752e415722a83aa00049f80ff3/starlette/requests.py#L167) and [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/212fa46b23be0701a5963cdeff14f05ed352e22a/starlette/datastructures.py#L674), respectively):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Request

app = FastAPI()

def func(request: Request):
    request.state.test = 'test value'

@app.get('/', dependencies=[Depends(func)])
def root(request: Request):
    return request.state.test
```

If you would like that state (i.e., `test` attribute above) to be globally accessible from any request/user, you might want to store it on the application instance, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71298949/17865804), as well [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71465282/17865804) answer.

### Option 2

Instead of adding `dependencies=[Depends(test)]` to the decorator of the endpoint, you could use the [dependency injection](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#first-steps) directly, by defining `test` (in this example) as an endpoint parameter and using `Depends`. You could then have the dependency function returning the attribute. Using this option, however, you would have to do this for every endpoint in your app/router, if you had to define a global dependency for the entire app/router, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74105859/17865804).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Request

app = FastAPI()

def func(request: Request):
    return 'test value'

@app.get('/')
def root(request: Request, test: str = Depends(func)):
    return test
```

Comment: Perfect, that really saved me lots of time.