# Frame Rate Drops When Processing Video Frames in Separate Thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, thread-safety, fastapi

I'm working on a video processing application in Python, where I have three main tasks: updating frames from a video source, processing frames (like object detection), and sending frames to a client to display. I'm using asyncio for asynchronous operations(updating and sending the frames) and threading for frame processing.

Problem:
As soon as I activate frame processing in a separate thread (process_frame method), the frame rate of sending frames to the client drops significantly, causing a noticeable delay in the live feed. The processing task is supposed to analyze the newest frame from the buffer and add the frame and frame id in a bounding box buffer, Then in the send frame function i compare the oldest frame id with the oldest bounding box id, when they match i draw on the bounding box before sending the frame(This allows me to have a smooth display of frames and manage to process frames as processing of frames is slower than the updating of frames) So I am then able to sync the two.. I'm using a Queue for thread-safe operations.

I expected that by running process_frame in a separate thread, it wouldn't affect the frame updating (update_frame) and sending (send_frame) tasks. However, the live feed is lagging behind real-time significantly when process_frame is active.

```
# Simplified version of the code
import threading
import asyncio
from queue import Queue

class VideoProcessor:
    # ... [initializations] ...

    def __init__(self):
        # ... [variables and queues initialization] ...
        self.frame_buffer = Queue(maxsize=15)
        self.bbox_buffer = Queue(maxsize=15)
        # ... [other initializations] ...

async def update_frame(self, url):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
        while self.is_updating_frame:
            if cap is None or not cap.isOpened():
                logger.warning("Failed to connect to camera, retrying...")
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
                await asyncio.sleep(self.reconnect_delay)
                continue

            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                frame_id = self.frame_counter
                self.frame_buffer.put({'frame': frame, 'id': frame_id})
                self.frame_counter = (self.frame_counter + 1) % self.MAX_FRAME_COUNT

                # Check if there are enough frames in the buffer before sending
                if self.is_sending_frame and self.frame_buffer.qsize() >= 10:
                    await self.send_frame(self.websocket)
            else:
                logger.warning("Failed to read frame, reconnecting...")
                cap.release()
                cap = None
                await asyncio.sleep(self.reconnect_delay)

            await asyncio.sleep(0.01)

        if cap is not None:
            cap.release()
            logger.info("--Frame update stopped")



    def process_frame(self, service_type):
        try:
            logger.info("-Frame processing Started")
            self.current_service_type = service_type
            while self.is_processing_frame:
                if not self.frame_buffer.empty():
                    frame_data = self.frame_buffer.queue[-1]
                    frame = frame_data['frame']
                    frame_id = frame_data['id']
                    # Call the synchronous function directly
                    if service_type == "Object_Detect":
                        bbox = self.process_OD(frame)
                        #logger.info(self.last_bbox)
                    elif service_type == "Face_Rec":
                        bbox = self.process_FR(frame)
                        #logger.info(self.last_bbox)
                    # If no bounding box is found, clear the bbox_buffer and reset last_sent_bbox
                    #if self.bbox_buffer:
                    #    logger.info(f"FRAME ID:{frame_id}, BBOX ID:{self.bbox_buffer[-1]['id']}")
                    if bbox is not None:
                        self.bbox_buffer.put({'bbox': bbox, 'id': frame_id})
                        
                    if bbox is None:
                        while not self.bbox_buffer.empty():
                            self.bbox_buffer.get_nowait()
                        self.last_sent_bbox = None
                    
                    if not self.is_processing_frame:
                        self.last_bbox = None
                        self.last_sent_bbox = None
                        while not self.bbox_buffer.empty():
                            self.bbox_buffer.get_nowait()
                
            self.is_processing_frame = False
            logger.info("--Frame processing Stopped")
        except WebSocketDisconnect:
            logger.info("process_frame WebSocket disconnected during model operation")
            self.is_sending_frame = False
        finally:
            logger.info("--Frame processing Stopped")






    async def send_frame(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        # Check if there are frames in the buffer
        if self.frame_buffer and self.is_sending_frame:
            # Get and remove the oldest frame from the buffer
            frame_data = self.frame_buffer.get()
            frame_to_send = frame_data['frame']
            frame_id = frame_data['id']

            # Process bbox_buffer
            if not self.bbox_buffer.empty() and self.bbox_buffer.queue[0]['id'] == frame_id:
                bbox_data = self.bbox_buffer.get()
                self.last_bbox = bbox_data['bbox']

            # Draw the bounding box if available
            if self.last_bbox:
                if self.current_service_type == "Object_Detect":
                    frame_to_send = OD_BBOX(frame_to_send, self.last_bbox)
                elif self.current_service_type == "Face_Rec":
                    frame_to_send = FR_BBOX(frame_to_send, self.last_bbox)

            # Encode and send the frame
            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame_to_send, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 30])
            compressed_image_bytes = buffer.tobytes()
            try:
                await websocket.send_bytes(compressed_image_bytes)
            except WebSocketDisconnect:
                logger.info("WebSocket disconnected during data sending. Stopping send_frame.")
                self.is_sending_frame = False
                return
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"An unexpected error occurred in send_frame: {e}")
                self.is_sending_frame = False
                return
```

Details:

- The `update_frame` method continuously reads frames from a camera and
  puts them into self.frame_buffer.
- The `process_frame` method, running in a separate thread, processes the
  newest frame for object detection and puts the results into
  self.bbox_buffer.
- The `send_frame` method sends frames from self.frame_buffer to a
  client. It is supposed to sync with self.bbox_buffer for drawing
  bounding boxes.
- When p`rocess_frame` is not running, update_frame and send_frame work
  as expected with no significant delay.
- All shared resources are accessed in a thread-safe manner using
  Queue.

### Question:

What could be causing the frame rate to drop when process_frame is active, and how can I resolve this issue to maintain a real-time or near-real-time frame rate?

### UPDATED CODE USING FULL ASYNC METHODS:

Here i implemented a full async methodology and shared the full code as requested in the comment of the thread, it did improve the speed abit, but i dont understand why its slowing down the `update_frame` and `send_frame` functions:

```
class VideoProcessor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame_buffer_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.bbox_buffer_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.current_frame = None
        self.last_bbox = None  # Store the last bounding box here
        self.reconnect_delay = 5
        self.model_name = "best"
        self.OTFaceRecognition = False
        self.yoloAccuracy = 0.7
        self.apply_tracking = False
        self.process_frame_width = 1280  #  
        self.process_frame_height = 720  #  480
        self.frame_width = None
        self.frame_height = None
        self.client_frame_width = None
        self.client_frame_height = None
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        self.FaceRec= False
        self.FaceDetection = False
        self.FDAccuracy = 0.5
        self.FRAccuracy = 0.17
        self.oTFDAccuracy = 0.5
        self.oTFRAccuracy = 0.3
        self.MultiFaceDetection = False
        self.class_colors = {}
        self.update_frame_thread = None
        self.last_sent_bbox = None
        self.MAX_FRAME_COUNT = 1000
        self.websocket = None
        self.is_updating_frame = False
        self.is_processing_frame = False
        self.is_sending_frame = False
        self.current_service_type = None
        self.frame_buffer = deque(maxlen=10)  # Buffer for frames with max size 30
        self.bbox_buffer = deque(maxlen=10)  # Buffer for bboxes with max size 30
        self.frame_counter = 0  # Counter for the frame ID
        self.executor = ThreadPoolExecutor() 

    async def websocket_control(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        logger.info("Server Started")

        while True:
            try:
                self.websocket = websocket
                data = await self.websocket.receive_text()
                message = json.loads(data)
                logging.info("Received new message")
                if message["command"] == "Start_Stream":
                    logger.info("Stream Message Received")
                    url = message.get("camera_url")
                    logger.info(f"START STREAM URL:{url}")
                    self.is_sending_frame = True
                    if not self.is_updating_frame:
                        self.is_updating_frame = True
                        asyncio.create_task(self.update_frame(url))
                if message["command"] == "Change_Camera":
                    logger.info("CAMERA CHANGED")
                    url = message.get("camera_url")
                    logger.info(f"CHANGE CAMERA URL:{url}")
                    await self.shutdown_camera()

                    # Restart frame update with new camera URL
                    self.is_updating_frame = True
                    asyncio.create_task(self.update_frame(url))
                    
                    if self.is_processing_frame:
                        asyncio.create_task(self.process_frame(service_type))

                if message["command"    ] == "Disconnect_Camera":
                    logger.info("CAMERA DISCONNECTED")
                    # Stop the current frame update and sending frame tasks
                    self.is_updating_frame = False
                    self.is_sending_frame = False
                    self.is_processing_frame = False
                    await self.shutdown_camera()



                if message["command"] == "Start_Processing":
                    self.is_processing_frame = True
                    logger.info("Start_Processing Message Received")
                    service_type = message.get("service_type")
                    url = message.get("camera_url")
                    if  service_type == "Object_Detect":
                        self.model_name = message.get("model_name")
                        self.OTFaceRecognition = message.get("OTrunFaceRec")
                        self.yoloAccuracy = message.get("yoloAccuracy")
                        self.oTFDAccuracy = message.get("oTFDAccuracy")
                        self.oTFRAccuracy = message.get("oTFRAccuracy")
                        self.apply_tracking = message.get("apply_tracking")  
                    if  service_type == "Face_Rec":
                        self.MultiFaceDetection = message.get("MultiFaceDetection")
                        self.FaceDetection = message.get("FaceDetection")
                        self.FaceRec = message.get("FaceRec")
                    if  service_type == "Motion_Detect":
                        self.MultiFaceDetection = message.get("MultiFaceDetection")
                        self.FaceDetection = message.get("FaceDetection")
                        self.FaceRec = message.get("FaceRec")
                    asyncio.create_task(self.process_frame(service_type))
    
                if message["command"] == "Stop_Processing":
                    self.is_processing_frame = False
                    self.last_bbox = None
                    logger.info("MESSAGE Stop_Processing")

                if message["command"] == "update_OD_settings":
                    logger.info("Updated OD SETTINGS")
                    self.model_name = message.get("model_name")
                    self.OTFaceRecognition = message.get("OTrunFaceRec")
                    self.yoloAccuracy = message.get("yoloAccuracy")
                    self.oTFDAccuracy = message.get("oTFDAccuracy")
                    self.oTFRAccuracy = message.get("oTFRAccuracy")

                    self.apply_tracking = message.get("apply_tracking")    


                if message["command"] == "update_FR_settings":           
                    logger.info("Updated FR SETTINGS")
                    self.FDAccuracy = message.get("FDAccuracy")
                    self.FRAccuracy = message.get("FRAccuracy")
                    self.MultiFaceDetection = message.get("MultiFaceDetection")
                    self.FaceDetection = message.get("FaceDetection")
                    self.FaceRec = message.get("FaceRec")                   
                    
            except WebSocketDisconnect as e:  # For other disconnection codes
                logger.info(f"websocket_control disconnected with code: {e.code}")
                self.is_sending_frame = False
                self.websocket = None
                # Cleanup resources and break the loop
                break

    async def shutdown_camera(self):
        self.is_updating_frame = False
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)  # Short delay to ensure update_frame stops
        self.frame_buffer.clear()
        self.frame_counter = 0





    async def update_frame(self, url):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
        
        while self.is_updating_frame:
            if cap is None or not cap.isOpened():
                logger.warning("Failed to connect to camera, retrying...")
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
                await asyncio.sleep(self.reconnect_delay)
                continue

            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret:
                frame_id = self.frame_counter
                self.frame_buffer.append({'frame': frame, 'id': frame_id})
                self.frame_counter = (self.frame_counter + 1) % self.MAX_FRAME_COUNT

                # Check if there are enough frames in the buffer before sending
                if self.is_sending_frame and len(self.frame_buffer) >= 10:
                    await self.send_frame(self.websocket)
            else:
                logger.warning("Failed to read frame, reconnecting...")
                cap.release()
                cap = None
                await asyncio.sleep(self.reconnect_delay)

            await asyncio.sleep(0.01)

        if cap is not None:
            cap.release()
            logger.info("--Frame update stopped")


    async def process_frame(self, service_type):
        try:
            logger.info("-Frame processing Started")
            self.current_service_type = service_type
            while self.is_processing_frame:
                if self.frame_buffer:
                    # Access the last frame data without removing it from the buffer
                    frame_data = self.frame_buffer[-1]
                    frame = frame_data['frame']

                    if service_type == "Object_Detect":
                        bbox = await self.process_OD(frame)
                    elif service_type == "Face_Rec":
                        bbox = await self.process_FR(frame)
                    if bbox is not None:
                        frame_data['bbox'] = bbox 
                await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
            self.last_bbox = None
            for frame_data in self.frame_buffer:
                frame_data['bbox'] = None
                
            self.is_processing_frame = False
            logger.info("--Frame processing Stopped")
        except WebSocketDisconnect:
            logger.info("process_frame WebSocket disconnected during model operation")
            self.is_sending_frame = False
        finally:
            logger.info("--Frame processing Stopped")



    async def send_frame(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        if self.frame_buffer and self.is_sending_frame:
            frame_data = self.frame_buffer.popleft()
            frame_to_send = frame_data['frame']
            bbox = frame_data.get('bbox')
            if bbox is not None:
                # New bounding box found, draw it
                self.last_bbox = bbox
            elif self.last_bbox:
                # No new bbox, use the last known bbox, if it exists
                bbox = self.last_bbox
            # Draw the bounding box if it exists
            if bbox:
                if self.current_service_type == "Object_Detect":
                    frame_to_send = OD_BBOX(frame_to_send, bbox)
                elif self.current_service_type == "Face_Rec":
                    frame_to_send = FR_BBOX(frame_to_send, bbox)
            # Encode and send the frame
            _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame_to_send, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 30])
            compressed_image_bytes = buffer.tobytes()
            try:
                await websocket.send_bytes(compressed_image_bytes)
            except WebSocketDisconnect:
                self.is_sending_frame = False
                return
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"An unexpected error occurred in send_frame: {e}")
                self.is_sending_frame = False
                return



    



    async def process_OD(self, frame):
        _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 30])
        face_frame_bytes = buffer.tobytes()

        data = aiohttp.FormData()
        data.add_field('model_name', str(self.model_name))
        data.add_field('runFaceRec', str(self.OTFaceRecognition))
        data.add_field('yoloAccuracy', str(self.yoloAccuracy))
        data.add_field('oTFDAccuracy', str(self.oTFDAccuracy))
        data.add_field('oTFRAccuracy', str(self.oTFRAccuracy))
        data.add_field('apply_tracking', str(self.apply_tracking))
        data.add_field('image_file', face_frame_bytes, filename='frame.jpg', content_type='image/jpg')

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.post('http://detection_service:8000/api/v1/detections/process', data=data) as response:
                processed_result = await response.json()
                return processed_result
        
            

    async def process_FR(self, frame):
        _, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 30])
        face_frame_bytes = buffer.tobytes()

        data = aiohttp.FormData()
        data.add_field('FaceRecognitionStandAloneFlag', str(self.FaceRec))
        data.add_field('MultiFaceDetection', str(self.MultiFaceDetection))
        data.add_field('FaceDetection', str(self.FaceDetection))
        data.add_field('FRDetectionAccuracy', str(self.FDAccuracy))
        data.add_field('FRRecognitionAccuracy', str(self.FRAccuracy))
        data.add_field('image_file', face_frame_bytes, filename='frame.jpg', content_type='image/jpg')

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.post('http://recognition_service:8000/api/v1/recognitions/process', data=data) as response:
                processed_result = await response.json()
                return processed_result
```

Comment: You can't use threads in Python to do work in parallel for CPU-bound work that in isn't offloaded to code outside the interpreter. The GIL will prevent bytecode instructions from multiple threads from being executed at once. You need multiple interpreters (multiprocessing) to do CPU-bound work within the interpreter in parallel.

Comment: @Carcigenicate So in simple terms I need to change the process_frame from a thread to a process right?

Comment: Changing `process_frame` to multiprocessing will have you spend a lot of time serializing and deserializing frames, so that likely won't help that much. You also have lots of blocking (not async) calls in those async functions, that won't help you either. Can you show us the actual processing functions a bit more?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: @AKX I just updated with my new code using full async methodology and it seems to have improved the speed of the update_frame and send_frame functions but its still lagging, and the weird thing is that process_frame is running really fast, so i cant understand the lag.

Comment: @Chris thanks allot Chris! This gave me a good understanding, and i have implemented a full async system, but im still encountering this issue...

Comment: You still have a bunch of sync calls - everything cv2 for instance.

Comment: Could you kindly indicate what exactly? Just because Im just confused as to which exactly. In addition I wanted to ask. in the process_frame function it has two functions called process_od and process_fr(process object detection and facial recogntion) it seems that if i run it in a separate thread, it seems to run faster:"self.loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, self.process_OD, frame)". Is this a good approach ? I can share the updated code. and thanks for your input @AKX

Comment: As mentioned by @AKX, every `cv2` operation, such as `cap.read()`, `cv2.imencode`, etc., still runs *synchronously*. Also, you should make sure to use an `if..elif` structure, where conditions are mutually exclusive, such as `if message["command"]`. Further, you shouldn't be creating a new instance of your HTTP client every time that those `process()` functions are being called, but instead, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) on how to initialise an HTTP client connection and reuse it.

Comment: Hello @Chris Thanks for the feedback. Using await directly with synchronous functions like those provided by OpenCV (cap.read(), cv2.imencode, etc.) is not possible because these functions are not designed to be asynchronous.As a solution to that, would running asyncio.run_in_executor be a viable solution?  As it  provides a way to run these blocking, synchronous functions in a separate thread or process?