# fastAPI Depends does not resolve coroutine dependency when @alru_cache is used

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi

Let's say I have a class `Foo` that need a running event loop when the constructor is called.
I want to use the [dependency injection system of fastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) to provide the same instance of the `Foo` class to my endpoints.

The `Foo` itself is not a singleton, so I make create a getter function `get_foo()` that always returns the same instance.

So a minimal example looks like this:

```py
import asyncio
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from async_lru import alru_cache
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

app = FastAPI()


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

        async def _task() -> None:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            print(self.value)

        self._task = asyncio.create_task(_task())


@alru_cache  # makes it singleton-like
async def get_foo() -> Foo:
    return Foo(42)


@app.get("/")
async def root(foo: Annotated[Foo, Depends(get_foo)]):
    return {"message": foo.value}   # crashes here: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'value'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app=app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

This crashes with `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'value'`. Make `get_foo()` sync does not work either: `RuntimeError: no running event loop`.

If I remove the `@alru_cache` it works, but it is no longer a singleton-like object as desired.

What should I do to make it work as expected?

Comment: An alternative solution would be to create the object at `startup` and add it to the `request.state`, which would allow you to reuse it in every endpoint. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) for more details.

Comment: Yes, that's also works. But it has the downside that the lifespan funcion grows if I have `n` resources like `Foo` not just one. Having a singleton-like getter for each resource and only declare the needed resources in each endpoint independently seems to be cleaner and better maintainable to me.

Comment: Another downside is that you can't override it easily as you can do with dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77855759/10975692) of [yurii-motov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20301996/yurii-motov) is correct but can be slightly improved.

The avoid the need of duplicating the getter function I replaced `@alru_cache` with a small decorator of my own that does the same for my case and returns an `async` function which is automatically awaited by the dependency injection system of `fastAPI` as desired.

So here is my solution:

```py
import asyncio
from functools import wraps
from typing import Annotated, Callable, Awaitable, ParamSpec, TypeVar

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

app = FastAPI()


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

        async def _task() -> None:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            print(self.value)

        self._task = asyncio.create_task(_task())


P = ParamSpec('P')
R = TypeVar('R')


def cached(f: Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[R]]:
    cache: R | None = None

    @wraps(f)
    async def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        nonlocal cache

        if cache is not None:
            return cache

        cache = await f(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache

    return wrapper


@cached  # makes it singleton-like
async def get_foo() -> Foo:
    return Foo(42)


@app.get("/")
async def root(foo: Annotated[Foo, Depends(get_foo)]):
    return {"message": foo.value}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app=app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you have to do is awaiting the value received in the `foo` parameter:

```
@app.get("/")
async def root(foo: Annotated[Foo, Depends(get_foo)]):
    return {"message": (await foo).value}
```

Either that, or just make `get_foo` itself a synch function:

```
@lru_cache  # makes it singleton-like
def get_foo() -> Foo:
    return Foo(42)
```

Comment: Awaiting in every endpoint is quite ugly, since fastAPI should do this for me - and yes, normally it does so: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/#to-async-or-not-to-async

Making it sync dos not work since there is no running event loop which is required by the constructor of foo. Just execute it and see the error.

Comment: if you have a co-routine, you have to wait it to get its return value. That is how async works - there is no "ugly" - there is simpy no point in `get_foo` to be a co-routine there.

Comment: As I said: `fastAPI` normally awaits those async dependencies fr me - that's how dependency injection works in `fastAPI`. Just comment out the `@alru_cache` line in my example code and how it works. There is no need for `await`.

If `get_foo` is not `async` it would crash with the error `RuntimeError: no running event loop`. Therefore there is a need for the `get_foo` function to be `async`.

Comment: @jsbueno, what if you want to override this dependency in tests? What if you use this dependency twice in your dependency tree (as sub-dependency in other dependency)? I absolutely agree with DarkMath, that it's better to follow FastAPI style and not to await dependency manually.

Comment: if the parameter is an awaitable, it has to be awaited. What you are both saying is just nonsense. Either the function needs an awaitable parameter, or it needs a parameter that is no tan awaitable: changing the dependency, or changing it on tests still has to pass the function a conforming object.

Comment: Parameter is not awaitable. Parameter is object with type `Foo` and `Depends(get_foo)` in annotations. `Depends` automaticaly checks whether the function is awaitable or not (by signature) and await it.

Answer (score 1):

`alru_cache` wraps your `async` function in not an `async` function. So, FastAPI trying to resolve dependencies sees that your dependency is not an `async` function and doesn't await it.

To solve this you can add one more function and apply `alru_cache` to it, then call this function in your dependency function:

```
import asyncio
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from async_lru import alru_cache
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

app = FastAPI()


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

        async def _task() -> None:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            print(self.value)

        self._task = asyncio.create_task(_task())


@alru_cache  # makes it singleton-like
async def get_foo_internal() -> Foo:
    return Foo(42)


async def get_foo() -> Foo:
    return await get_foo_internal()


@app.get("/")
async def root(foo: Annotated[Foo, Depends(get_foo)]):
    return {"message": foo.value}   # crashes here: AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'value'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app=app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But it comes with the cost of boilerplate code. I wonder if there is a solution withut "duplicating" the `get_foo` function.

Comment: Another way is to implement caching in `Foo` class (class method that creates object or returns cached object).

Comment: It would be interesting to see if there is more elegant solution

Comment: Yes, there is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77858005/10975692