# How to parse an unpickleable object from startup event to a function used in multiprocessing pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, fastapi, starlette

Here are my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
from fastapi import FastAPI

clientObject = package.client() # object not pickle able
    
app = FastAPI()

def wrapper(func, retries, data_point):
# wrapper function to add a retry mechanism
    retry = 0
    while retry<retries:
        try:
            result = func(data_point)
        except Exception as err:
            result = err
            time.sleep(5) 
        else:
            break
    return result

def get_response(data_point):
# function use clientObject to get data from an Azure endpoint
    data_point = some_other_processes(data_point)
    ans = clientObject.process(data_point)
    return ans

def main(raw_data):
# main function where I use multiprocessing pool
    list_data_point = preprocess(raw_data)
    with Pool() as pool:
        wrapped_workload = partial(wrapper, 
                                   get_response,
                                   3)
        results = pool.map(wrapped_workload, list_data_point)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    return results


@app.post("/get_answer")
def get_answer(raw_data):
    processed_data = main(raw_data)
    return processed_data
```

The code above works fine if i declare `clientObject` from the begining (as a global variable).
But if i store it as an object in `app.state`like this:

```
@app.on_event("start_up")
def start_connection():
    app.state.clientObject = package.client()
```

and access it inside `get_response` function like this:

```
def get_response(data_point): 
     data_point = some_other_processes(data_point)
     ans = app.state.clientObject.process(data_point)
     return ans
```

it throws an error: '**State**' object has no attribute `clientObject`. However, the `app.state.clientObject` is still available inside `main()` function.

Also, due to the `clientObject` is not pickleable, I cannot pass it as an argument to `get_response(data_point, clientObject)` function.

Is there any way that I could initiate the `clientObject` on startup, store it in a variable and access it from a function used in multiprocessing pool? (without declaring it as global)

**Edit**: *This is my solution followed by suggestion of Frank Yellin below*:

```
def initialize_workers():
    global clientObject
    clientObject = package.client()

def get_response(data_point):
    global clientObject
    data_point = some_other_processes(data_point)
    ans = clientObject.process(data_point)
    return ans

def main(raw_data):
    list_data_point = preprocess(raw_data)
    with Pool(initializer=initialize_workers) as pool:
        wrapped_workload = partial(wrapper, 
                                   get_response,
                                   3)
        results = pool.map(wrapped_workload, list_data_point)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    return results
```

Comment: What exactly is `package.client()`? How is it pickle:d? If you control the source, could you not make it so that on reading in the pickle data, you initiate it too? And if you're trying to share a state via a common interface, perhaps a database is a more suitable? I know.. "instead of solving what you're asking - do this" kind of thing, but pickle data is perhaps not perfect here anyway? redis? Maybe I'm missing some obvious feature you're trying to achieve here but never seen it being done with pickle in general. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html maybe?

Comment: @Torxed to answer your questions: `package.client()` is a connection object and I'm not in control of the source. What I have tried to achieve is a way to initialize unpicklable object for workers processes. Frank Yellin have pointed out what I need to do to achieve that. Thank you for your response though.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) answer your question? Related answer can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804)

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately, it does not. But thank you anyway. It was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because, as you mentioned `clientObject` is not a pickleable object.  It is not an object that you can just copy from one process and use in another. Each process needs its own `clientObject`.

So you need to make sure that each process, on start up, creates the `clientObject`.  The way your code words is certainly one way.

An alternative, way is to use the `initializer` and `initargs` arguments when you create the `Pool`.  This specifies a function and its arguments that is called each time a new process starts.  This function would be a good place to create your `clientObject` and store it in a global or in your `app.state`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I'm looking for. I've edited the solution to my question above!